# jqueryUI Auto complete multiple data with image dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I tried the follwing code

```
$("#txt_external_company_users_search").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({url: "user_controller.php", data: {name: $("#txt_external_company_users_search").val(),
                method: 'ajax_search_external_user'},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.projects);
                    console.info(data);

                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txt_external_company_users_search").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txt_external_company_users_search").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        }
    })
            .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + "<img style=\"width: 30px; border-radius: 100px;\" src='" + img_path + "' />" + item.id + " - " + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

and  this is what i have in user_controller.php for ajax request

```
echo "{projects : [
        {
            value: 'apple',
            label: 'apple',
            id: '23',
            desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
            icon: 'jquery_32x32.png'
        },
        {
            value: 'banana',
            label: 'banana',
            id: '231',
            desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
            icon: 'jquery_32x32.png'
        },
        {
            value: 'pineapple',
            label: 'pineapple',
            id: '232',
            desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
            icon: 'jquery_32x32.png'
        },


    ]}";
```

If i specify the souce as a normal js variable in the same structure this works fine but when i use the ajax request it doesn't work. Please help

Comment: wha does `console.info(data);` print?

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`. You shouldn't be using both, and what is even strange is that you're specifying different values for them. `ajax_search_external_user` request type?!!